# Comparing the total values of strings?

Tags: c, string

Say I got two strings like

Input 1: "xyz789"
Input 2 "mno123"

Is there a way to compare their values and then output whether S1 is Greater , Equal or Less than S2?

Im doing this by hand with only the standard lib, so far have only gotten to checking their lengths (which is a safe assumption that a longer string is larger, but it gets harder when comparing similar lengths.

```
int compare_string(char *s1, char *s2)
{
   while(*s1==*s2)
   {
      if ( *s1 == '\0' || *s2 == '\0' )
         break;

      s1++;
      s2++;
   }
   if( *s1 == '\0' && *s2 == '\0' )
      return 0;
   else
      return -1;
}
```

Comment: You mean something like `strcmp`?

Comment: What do you mean by "compare their values"?

Comment: Do you want to add up the characters and compare the totals?  Why would a longer string necessarily be "larger"?

Comment: What do you mean by "S1 is Greater , Equal or Less than S2"?
If they have the same length, whats the criteria you would like to evaluate?

Comment: Hi guys yeah something like strcmp, but i wont use it because i dont want to use any string funcs, AND more importantly strcmp only outputs a equal or not equal rather than the 3 outpts i want. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: Ascii values would be the criteria i would like to calculate

Comment: @JoC What are "the three outputs you want"? You haven't even mentioned the outputs you want. Apart from that, read the manual of `strcmp()`. "strcmp only outputs a equal or not equal" is **just wrong.** It tells you the lexicographical order of its arguments.

Comment: Oh I would like a  1, 0 or -1 for Greater Than, Equals To or Less Than. Kinda like in here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

I just cant seem to figure out how they did it

Comment: @JoC They did that by calling `strcmp()`. You still couldn't be bothered to read that man page, right?

Answer (score 3):

[The function you are looking for is named `strcmp()`. This function is defined to return three possible values, depending on whether the first string is greater than, equal to, or less than the second string. For the sake of completeness, this entire paragraph is a link to the man page for the `strcmp()` function. Please make sure to read it.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcmp.html)

<sub>Strictly speaking, it isn't precisely correct to say that the function returns three possible values. The function returns a negative or positive value if the strings differ, but there's no limitation imposed on *what* negative or positive value is returned. In other words, it isn't guaranteed to return only `-1`, `0`, or `1`.</sub>